# OpenXML DataBinding not working with a namespace

Tags: data-binding, openxml, office-js, openxml-sdk, office-addins

I have a Word document, which have a Content Control XML.

This is the code of the content control from the `document.xml`:

```
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
        <w:alias w:val="contentcontrol1"/>
        <w:tag w:val=""/>
        <w:id w:val="-1926948802"/>
        <w:showingPlcHdr/>
        <w:dataBinding w:xpath="/Root[1]/Node[1]" w:storeItemID="{C2F77B86-6131-4922-803B-54FACB654C16}"   />
        <w15:appearance w15:val="tags"/>
        <w:text/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p w14:paraId="04EB220B" w14:textId="0D23CD24" w:rsidR="009A2940" w:rsidRDefault="00C15D80"/>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

And this is the code of the Custom Xml Part (from `CustomXml/Items3.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="">
    <Node>VALUE1</Node>
</Root>
```

And the data binding is working well: when I open the Word document, the content control shows the value VALUE1.

However, if I add a namespace to the Custom Xml, it is not working anymore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://example">
    <Node>VALUE1</Node>
</Root>
```

I tried to change the dataBinding like these:

```
<w:dataBinding w:xpath="//ns0:Root[1]/Node[1]" w:storeItemID="{C2F77B86-6131-4922-803B-54FACB654C16}"  w:prefixMappings="xmlns:ns0='http://example'" />
<w:dataBinding w:xpath="http://example:Root[1]/Node[1]" w:storeItemID="{C2F77B86-6131-4922-803B-54FACB654C16}" />
<w:dataBinding w:xpath="[namespace-uri()='http://example']/Node[1]" w:storeItemID="{C2F77B86-6131-4922-803B-54FACB654C16}" />
```

But the value VALUE1 is still not being retrieved.

What can I do to have a dataBinding working with namespace?

Comment: Generally, Word seems to prefer having an *alias* to identify the namespace and to be used as an identifier with all the nodes. Does it work if you change the xml to `<x:Root xmlns:x="http://example">
    <x:Node>VALUE1</x:Node>
</x:Root>`

Comment: In my answer, I've provided a working example that shows how you should define the mapping for both your Custom XML with just the default namespace and @CindyMeister's version with a namespace prefix (which I'd also prefer).

Answer (score 0):

The unit test below demonstrates that you can bind your `w:sdt` element to a custom XML element having an XML namespace (e.g., "http://example.com") if, and only if, you use namespace prefixes (e.g., "ex") in the `w:prefixMappings` and `w:xpath` attributes of the `w:dataBinding` element.

Your custom XML element does not need a namespace prefix, though. Thus, both of the following XML documents will work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ex:Root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
  <ex:Node>VALUE1</ex:Node>
</ex:Root>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <Node>VALUE1</Node>
</Root>
```

Here comes the unit test:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomXmlDataProperties;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
using Xunit;

namespace CodeSnippets.Tests.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
{
    public class DataBoundContentControlTests
    {
        private const WordprocessingDocumentType Type = WordprocessingDocumentType.Document;

        private const string NsPrefix = "ex";
        private const string NsName = "http://example.com";
        private static readonly XNamespace Ns = NsName;

        private static string CreateCustomXmlPart(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, XElement rootElement)
        {
            CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = mainDocumentPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
            customXmlPart.PutXDocument(new XDocument(rootElement));
            return CreateCustomXmlPropertiesPart(customXmlPart);
        }

        private static string CreateCustomXmlPropertiesPart(CustomXmlPart customXmlPart)
        {
            XElement rootElement = customXmlPart.GetXElement();
            if (rootElement == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

            string storeItemId = "{" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "}";

            // Create a ds:dataStoreItem associated with the custom XML part's root element.
            var dataStoreItem = new DataStoreItem
            {
                ItemId = storeItemId,
                SchemaReferences = new SchemaReferences()
            };

            if (rootElement.Name.Namespace != XNamespace.None)
            {
                dataStoreItem.SchemaReferences.AppendChild(new SchemaReference {Uri = rootElement.Name.NamespaceName});
            }

            // Create the custom XML properties part.
            var propertiesPart = customXmlPart.AddNewPart<CustomXmlPropertiesPart>();
            propertiesPart.DataStoreItem = dataStoreItem;
            propertiesPart.DataStoreItem.Save();

            return storeItemId;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanDataBindBlockLevelSdtToCustomXmlWithNsPrefixIfNsPrefixInPrefixMapping()
        {
            // The following root element has an explicitly created attribute
            // xmlns:ex="http://example.com":
            //
            //   <ex:Root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
            //     <ex:Node>VALUE1</ex:Node>
            //   </ex:Root>
            //
            var customXmlRootElement =
                new XElement(Ns + "Root",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + NsPrefix, NsName),
                    new XElement(Ns + "Node", "VALUE1"));

            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create("SdtBlock_NsPrefix_WithNsPrefixInMapping.docx", Type);

            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            string storeItemId = CreateCustomXmlPart(mainDocumentPart, customXmlRootElement);

            mainDocumentPart.PutXDocument(new XDocument(
                new XElement(W.document,
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w.NamespaceName),
                    new XElement(W.body,
                        new XElement(W.sdt,
                            new XElement(W.sdtPr,
                                new XElement(W.dataBinding,
                                    // Note the w:prefixMapping attribute WITH a namespace
                                    // prefix and the corresponding w:xpath atttibute.
                                    new XAttribute(W.prefixMappings, $"xmlns:{NsPrefix}='{NsName}'"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.xpath, $"{NsPrefix}:Root[1]/{NsPrefix}:Node[1]"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.storeItemID, storeItemId))),
                            new XElement(W.sdtContent,
                                new XElement(W.p)))))));

            // Note that we just added an empty w:p to the w:sdtContent element.
            // However, if you open the Word document created by the above code
            // in Microsoft Word, you should see a single paragraph saying
            // "VALUE1".
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanDataBindBlockLevelSdtToCustomXmlWithoutNsPrefixIfNsPrefixInPrefixMapping()
        {
            // The following root element has an implicitly created attribute
            // xmlns='http://example.com':
            //
            //   <Root xmlns="http://example.com">
            //     <Node>VALUE1</Node>
            //   </Root>
            //
            var customXmlRootElement =
                new XElement(Ns + "Root",
                    new XElement(Ns + "Node", "VALUE1"));

            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create("SdtBlock_DefaultNs_WithNsPrefixInMapping.docx", Type);

            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            string storeItemId = CreateCustomXmlPart(mainDocumentPart, customXmlRootElement);

            mainDocumentPart.PutXDocument(new XDocument(
                new XElement(W.document,
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w.NamespaceName),
                    new XElement(W.body,
                        new XElement(W.sdt,
                            new XElement(W.sdtPr,
                                new XElement(W.dataBinding,
                                    // Note the w:prefixMapping attribute WITH a namespace
                                    // prefix and the corresponding w:xpath atttibute.
                                    new XAttribute(W.prefixMappings, $"xmlns:{NsPrefix}='{NsName}'"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.xpath, $"{NsPrefix}:Root[1]/{NsPrefix}:Node[1]"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.storeItemID, storeItemId))),
                            new XElement(W.sdtContent,
                                new XElement(W.p)))))));

            // Note that we just added an empty w:p to the w:sdtContent element.
            // However, if you open the Word document created by the above code
            // in Microsoft Word, you should see a single paragraph saying
            // "VALUE1".
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CannotDataBindBlockLevelSdtToCustomXmlWithDefaultNsIfNotNsPrefixInPrefixMapping()
        {
            // The following root element has an implicitly created attribute
            // xmlns='http://example.com':
            //
            //   <Root xmlns="http://example.com">
            //     <Node>VALUE1</Node>
            //   </Root>
            //
            var customXmlRootElement =
                new XElement(Ns + "Root",
                    new XElement(Ns + "Node", "VALUE1"));

            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create("SdtBlock_DefaultNs_WithoutNsPrefixInMapping.docx", Type);

            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            string storeItemId = CreateCustomXmlPart(mainDocumentPart, customXmlRootElement);

            mainDocumentPart.PutXDocument(new XDocument(
                new XElement(W.document,
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "w", W.w.NamespaceName),
                    new XElement(W.body,
                        new XElement(W.sdt,
                            new XElement(W.sdtPr,
                                new XElement(W.dataBinding,
                                    // Note the w:prefixMapping attribute WITHOUT a namespace
                                    // prefix and the corresponding w:xpath atttibute.
                                    new XAttribute(W.prefixMappings, $"xmlns='{NsName}'"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.xpath, "Root[1]/Node[1]"),
                                    new XAttribute(W.storeItemID, storeItemId))),
                            new XElement(W.sdtContent,
                                new XElement(W.p)))))));

            // Note that we just added an empty w:p to the w:sdtContent element.
            // If you open the Word document created by the above code in Microsoft
            // Microsoft Word, you will only see an EMPTY paragraph.
        }
    }
}
```

The correct values for the `w:xpath` attributes are either:

1. `w:xpath="ex:Root[1]/ex:Node[1]"` (without a leading '/') or
2. `w:xpath="/ex:Root[1]/ex:Node[1]"` (with a leading '/').

The first one is fine if `ex:Root` is reserved for the single root element. The second one explicitly states that you want to start at the root element. Even the next one works, although specifying "the first descendant `ex:Root`" element does not make a lot of sense for the root element:

3. `w:xpath="//ex:Root[1]/ex:Node[1]"` (with a leading "//").